# Disable last option to be checked in Jquery Multiselect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using jquery multiselect in my project,when user clicks on checkall then how can i stop this function to check last option in jquery multiselect?

like if i have 4 option in my jquery multiselect and if user clicks on check all i want intial three option to be checked but last option is unchecked.
any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Should they ever be able to check the last option?

Comment: yeah they need to check manually..i mean apart from checkall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go updated solution here for plugin as well normal multiple checkbox with demo!

**Solution for multiselect Checkbox special condition to uncheck last checkbox on checkall**

Working MultiSelect jsfiddle for specific case regarding @Gautam's multiselect plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/fG6PT/82/

**HTML:**

```
<select multiple="multiple" class='multi'>
<option value="foo">foo</option>
<option value="bar">bar</option>
<option value="baz">baz</option>
<option value="toy">toy</option>
</select>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.multi').multiselect({

    // Uncheck the last checkbox when chaeckall happens.
    checkAll: function () {

       if ($(this).is(":last") == true){

          var arr = $(this).val().toString().split(',');
           // Work on the array length alert('===>' + arr.length);
           var l = arr.length;
           for(i=(l-1);i<l;i++){
               // so whatever the lenght is aim for the last element
                 $('input:checkbox[value="' + arr[i] + '"]').attr('checked', false);
           }
        }
    }

});
```

**Solution below is for normal Chckbox**

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ev7FX/5/

http://jsfiddle.net/Ev7FX/4/

**Html**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="4" />
<a href="#" title="" id="check">check all</a> <a href="#" title="" id="uncheck">uncheck all</a>​
```

**JQuery Code**

```
var all_checkboxes = jQuery(':checkbox');

jQuery('#check').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
       all_checkboxes.not(':last').prop('checked', true);
});

jQuery('#uncheck').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    all_checkboxes.prop('checked', false);
});​
```

This will help, cheers!

Comment: Thanks for reply your solution is working fine with normal multiselect...but iam facing issues with jquery Multiselect

Comment: Hiya Jquery multiselect? umm, how do you mean? DO you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ZUYRj/1/ another working solution for you which does not select last checkbox , Hope this helps, cheers

Comment: Please check this link http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/

Comment: hmm, something like `("select").multiselect({
checkAll: function () {
   $(".ui-multiselect-checkboxes").is(":last").attr("disabled","disabled");
});` perhaps?

Comment: Saweet - @frumbert  I did it bit different but nailed it give me 5 minutes to indent it nicely, cheer, and thanks for giving me hint, never worked on this plugin before, cheers

Comment: @Gautam you around mate - made a JS Fiddle and some code - Behavior every time you do check all the last option will be unchecked, Check my answer above (In my answer space), cheers

Comment: @Tats_innit  Thanks alotttttt :)  could you please tell how can show correct information in header..like link which you provided  http://jsfiddle.net/fG6PT/82/  working as i expected but in header its showing 4 selected but it should shold show 3 selected as last option is disabled

Comment: @Gautam take a look into the link you gave me - it must have an option property to set that to 3 , [Link] http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/ hope this helps for that slected option display.

Comment: @Tats_innit  how to do +1 to your ans...i really don't know :(

Comment: lol, sure i can guide you for that, please press the **up-arrow** key where green tick is present next to my **main answer**. the number 0 (zero) will become 1 (one) next to my answer, :) let me know if you can't find it.

Comment: yes i got it but that requires at least 15 reputation and right now i am having only 9...will do it defiantly once i reach there :)

Comment: Try now, now you got 15 + (magic :) so you can up vote now; and by the way i can hepk you with your other questions, its time for me to sleep (in 20 mins) but you have +1 rights now! cheers

Answer (score 0):

Capture the checkboxes, iterate through them, perform(or in your case, don't perform) a unique action for the last element found.

```
var ourCheckBoxes = $(":checkBoxes");
$.each(ourCheckBoxes, function(index,value){
  if(index = ourCheckBoxes.length -1){
    //this is our last element broski
  }
});
```

Comment: Hiya, sup man or can do like this as below [code] .not(':last').prop('checked', true); [code] , what do you reckon, cheers ;

Comment: They're the same, essentially. He's just hijacking the click function of the 'check all' element, and telling it apply a checkbox to all elements that are not last. I'm simply running a test against all checkboxes and provided a place where you can run (or not run) code. In your case, you'll want to do nothing inside of the if statement, and use `else{ $(this).prop('checked', true); }`

Comment: Yep, great to talk to you man, wonder about the this hacky requirement hence discussed, Have a good one!